# TypeError: can't convert undefined to object using hammer.js

Tags: jquery, hammer.js

I'm trying to use hammer.js and when I import it in I get this error.

> TypeError: can't convert undefined to object
>   element.style[ prop ] =
>   css_props[p];

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/hammer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.hammer.js"></script>

$(function(){

$(window).hammer({}).bind("hold swipe dragstart drag dragend swipe", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Comment: You probably need to choose one or the other, rather than including the standalone + the jQuery plugin.

Comment: The plugin requires hammer.js

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$("body").hammer()...
```

Instead of

```
$(window).hammer()...
```

I've also had trouble getting hammer to work correctly, it seems like it misses a lot of standard use cases (using window instead of "body", Backbone events, jQuery delegation) and doesn't do you many favors if you don't use it exactly like they want.